# How to vertically center image without :before

Tags: html, css, css-position, centering, pseudo-element

I was wondering if there was another way to center a dynamic sized image without using the pseudo element :before. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

I like this option from [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/). First you position the image at `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` of the container which puts the top left of the image at the center of the container. Then you fix its position by adding `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` which moves the image back by half the image size.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/150" class="center" />
</div>
```